# Unresolved reference retrofit2

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

Started a new project today targeting API28 using androidx libraries. When attempting to use either Retrofit or OkHTTP3 in my project, `gradle sync` runs fine, but when attempting to run on device, the kotlin compiler complains "Unresolved reference to retrofit2/okhttp".

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

//apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.opticalgenesis.lbp.ktlab"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion "P"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3'
}
```

Relevant kotlin code

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

class LoginConfirmActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val i = intent
        val data = i.data

        val u = Uri.parse(data.toString())
        val code = u.getQueryParameter("code")
        val state = u.getQueryParameter("state")

        val generatedState = getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(MainActivity.STATE_KEY, "")

        if (state == generatedState) {
            Log.d("OAUTH", code)
            val r = Retrofit.Builder().apply {
                baseUrl("https://gitlab.com/oauth")
                addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            }.build()
            val authApi = r.create(GitLabAuthApi::class.java)
            val codeResponse = authApi.getAccessToken(
                    Keys.appId,
                    Keys.secret,
                    code,
                    "authorization_code",
                    Keys.redirectUri)
            codeResponse.enqueue(object : Callback<CodeResponse> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<CodeResponse>?, response: Response<CodeResponse>) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        parseAndStoreCodeResults(response.body()!!)
                    } else {
                        Log.e("AUTH_TAG", "Attempt to get code resulted in error ${response.errorBody()}")
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<CodeResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {
                    t?.printStackTrace()
                }
            })
        } else {
            Log.e("AUTH_TAG", "States don't match.")
        }
    }
}
```

Error message
[image: errors]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please post the entire log message

Comment: @dazza5000 done

Comment: Can you try running `./gradlew --refresh-dependencies` and then doing an `Invalidate caches/Restart` ?

Comment: add a backslash at the end in your URL like: `"https://gitlab.com/oauth/"`. Let me know if this fixes your issue. Also can you update the question with the endpoint you specified in the interface ?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes Gradle might not be able to sync properly for some reason, including download timeout or other possible weird stuff, a way around it might be to set another version (hopefully more recent), then resync the Gradle

- For Retrofit, you can try a version from the [GitHub Version/Releases List](https://github.com/square/retrofit/releases)

Although if the problem persists, other causes can be internet/access to repositories issues, or IDE not being able to access valid catches for some reasons (like file permission changes, hardware problems, etc)

- One thing that has happened many times for me which is not a bad idea to look up, is to check proxy stuff, both from the IDE's settings, and also Properties'/Settings' files (that not sure if it's fixed now or not yet, but from personal experience, sometimes changing IDE's settings alone doesn't remove the settings from some properties files)
- One in a million chance also this might do something too: Files -> Invalidate Catches / Restart

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough points to comment or upvote yet but I had the same issue and fixed it with

**Files -> invalidate catches/restart.**

Into my dependencies of build.gradle.kts I have:

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0")
```

and then in one of my classes I had a few imports that were not recognize.  for instance:

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.Response
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. The only thing that helped was a gradle build tools downgrade to stable 3.1.3

project: build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's an old post but, i'm newer to Kotlin and the problem was not solved.

Files -> Invalidate Catches / Restart, worked for me on 2.9.0 retrofit/gson